# Angular 8/9 - Firebase CRUD - Update

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I make an app. web with Angular and Firebase.

I'm looking to update my elements but I can't adapt the Firebase help to my code: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

here is the code for my service with CRUD:

```
export class UsersService {

  users: User[] = [];
  userSubject = new Subject<User[]>();

  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
  }

  emitUsers() {
    this.userSubject.next(this.users)
  }

  saveUser() {
    firebase.database().ref('/users').set(this.users)
  }

  getUsers() {
    firebase.database().ref('/users')
      .on('value', (data) => {
        this.users = data.val() ? data.val() : []
        this.emitUsers();
      })
  }

  getSingleUsers(id: number) {
    return new Promise(
      (resolve, reject) => {
        firebase.database().ref('/users' + id).once('value')
          .then(
            (data) => {
              resolve(data.val())
            }, (error) => {
              reject(error)
            }
          )
      }
    )
  }


  createNewUser(newUser: User) {
    this.users.push(newUser);
    this.saveUser();
    this.emitUsers();
  }



  removeUser(user: User) {
    const userIndextoRemove = this.users.findIndex(
      (userEl) => {
        if (userEl === user) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    )
    this.users.splice(userIndextoRemove, 1);
    this.saveUser();
    this.emitUsers()
  }
}
```

how can I do ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: When you run this code in a debugger, what specific line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: I have no problem with the code below but Firebase being new to me I can't do the update in my service

in the Firebase documentation, there is an example but I can't adapt it.

I don't know if I should incorporate it into my service or into my component directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the data in the following way.

Please refer to this video
https://youtu.be/Ao4sdagqpvg